# "De ala fija" meaning

Tags: vocabulario, vocabulario-técnico

¡Hola!
En un artículo sobre las curiosidades de aeropuertos encontré una frase que no puedo entender. Incluso el traductor de Google no da respuesta comprensible.

> Este aeropuerto solamente es accesible para helicópteros y aviones pequeños, **de ala fija de despegue** y aterrizaje corto, ya que las dimensiones son muy restringidas; por lo que un Airbus A380 nunca aterrizaría allí.

Estaría agrecido por traducir la parte marcada.

Comment: El término inglés es [fixed-wing aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-wing_aircraft).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es una simple clasificación:

- Aeronaves (vehículos para ir por el aire):

  - Aerostatos (se mantienen arriba pasivamente):
    • Globos
    • Dirigibles
  - Aerodinos (se mantienen arriba activamente):

    - Ala giratoria:
      • Helicópteros
      • Etc.
    - ***Ala fija:***
      • Aviones
      • Planeadores
      • Ultraligeros
      • Etc.

La frase parece tener la coma mal puesta, me parece más comprensible así:

> Este aeropuerto solamente es accesible para helicópteros y aviones pequeños de ala fija, de despegue y aterrizaje corto, ya que [...]

De lo contrario parece que con la oración especificativa se esté negando la posibilidad de que un avión grande sea de ala fija cuando no es así.

Fuentes: [Aeronave](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronave), [aerostato](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerostato) y [aerodino](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodino) en Wikipedia.

Comment: He editado tu respuesta para eliminar el monoespaciado. Puedes deshacer el Edit si prefieres el formato anterior.

Comment: No, está bien así, gracias.